# Using the Apple Accelerate Framework vForce library to improve performance

Tags: c++, performance, accelerate-framework

I have successfully implemented the BLAS library from Apple's Accelerate Framework to improve the performance of my basic vector and matrix operations.

Being satisfied with this, I turned my attention to vForce to vectorize my basic math functions. Here I was a bit surprised to get quite poor performance compared to naive implementations (using automatic compiler optimization -Os).

As a simple benchmark, I ran the following test: Matrix is the basic Matrix type, using a double pointer, AccelerateMatrix is a subclass of Matrix which uses the exponentiation function from vForce:

```
Matrix A(vec_size);
AccelerateMatrix B(vec_size);
for (int i=0; i<vec_size;i++ ) {
    A[i] = i;
    B[i] = i;
}

double elapsed_time;

clock_t start = clock();
for(int i=0;i<reps;i++){
    A.exp();
    A.log();
}
clock_t stop = clock();

elapsed_time = (double)(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/reps;

cerr << "Basic matrix exponentiation/log time = " << elapsed_time << endl;


start = clock();
for(int i=0;i<reps;i++){
    B.exp();
    B.log();
}
stop = clock();

elapsed_time = (double)(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/reps;

cerr << "Accelerate matrix exponentiation/log time = " << elapsed_time << endl;
```

The exponentiate/log member functions are implemented as follows:

```
void AccelerateMatrix::exp(){
   int size =(int)this->getSize();
   this->goToStart();
   vvexp(this->ptr, this->ptr, &size);}

void Matrix::exp(){
    double *ptr = data;
    while (!atEnd()) {
        *ptr = std::exp(*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

data is the pointer to the first element of the double array.

Below is the output of the performance:

Number of matrix elements = 1000000

Basic matrix exponentiation/log time(secs) = 0.0089806

Accelerate matrix exponentiation/log time(secs) = 0.0149955

I am running in from XCode in Release mode. 
My processor is a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7.
The memory is 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue is to do with how vForce manipulates memory. Essentially it is not good at handling large matrices in one go. For `vec_size = 1000;` vForce computes the exponential/log twice as fast as the compiler optimised, naive version. I broke the larger example `vec_size = 1000000` up into batches of 1000 each, and lo and behold, the vForce implementation was twice as fast as the naive one. Nice!

Comment: Did you find anything similar when working with BLAS?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Accelerate framework technically is a BLAS implementation. I haven't yet implemented OpenBLAS, but reportedly it's performance is similar. I will report my findings here once I have implemented it. Also Intel MKL  supposedly offers a similar (if not slightly better) performance (although it's not for free). Sorry I haven't got the benchmarks to hand, I recall it was a pretty simple google search.

Comment: Yeah I'm not so worried about the performance per se, but just looking for any "gotchas" you might have seen, like the one above. I start implementing that part of my app next month.

Comment: vForce doesn't manipulate memory. That is your job.  It just does what you tell it to where you tell it to.  The issue is that you blew past the size of the L1 and L2 caches and are eating the latency to go to L3.  Do your log and exp on 16 kB chunks and it will work better.